# Change url based onanother link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make second url same as first url using jQuery. Please see my html code below. It is a list of `div`s and `a`s.

```
    <div class="text-center">

<h5 class="category"><a href="url" rel="tag">No need to change this url</a> </h5>

<div class="tx-div small"></div>

 <a href="url1"><p class="name">Url</p></a>

    <span class="price">
<div class="add-to-cart-button">
<a href="url2" rel="nofollow"  class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix" target="_blank">Change this to url1 </a>
</div>  


</div>


<div class="text-center">

<h5 class="category"><a href="url" rel="tag">No need to change this url</a> </h5>

<div class="tx-div small"></div>

 <a href="url1"><p class="name">Url</p></a>

    <span class="price">
<div class="add-to-cart-button">
<a href="url2" rel="nofollow"  class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix" target="_blank">Change this to url1 </a>
</div>  


</div>
```

Please help

Comment: The question is missing the attempted code, also somewhat _unclear_. [edit].

Comment: Have a look at `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated code:**

```
$('.text-center').each(function(){
  $('a:eq(2)', this).attr('href', $('a:eq(1)', this).attr('href'));
});
```

---

Try this code:

```
$('.fc').each(function(){
  $('.sec', this).attr('href', $('.fic', this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Looks the same except css class names. Just change css class names in my code and everything should work just fine.

Comment: But i can't add class name . And it don't have class name .

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Here is working example try....

```js
$(".text-center").find('.url1').each(function( i ) {
  var url1 = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).parent().find('.url2').attr('href',url1);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
 <h5 class="category"><a href="url" rel="tag">No need to change this url</a> </h5>
 <div class="tx-div small"></div>
  <a class="url1" href="url1"><p class="name">Url</p></a>
 <span class="price">
  <div class="add-to-cart-button">
  <a href="url2" rel="nofollow"  class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix url2" target="_blank">Change this to url1 </a>
  </div>  
 </span> 
</div>

<div class="text-center">
 <h5 class="category"><a href="url" rel="tag">No need to change this url</a> </h5>
 <div class="tx-div small"></div>
  <a class="url1" href="url11111"><p class="name">Url</p></a>
 <span class="price">
  <div class="add-to-cart-button">
  <a href="url22222" rel="nofollow"  class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button alt-button small clearfix url2" target="_blank">Change this to url1 </a>
  </div>  
 </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: But it is a loop of html  div . It is repeating .

Comment: Thank you  :) .. But url1 is always change . And it is dynamic . Please see the accepted answer .

Comment: @Manik i've edited the answer, please check use common class in for anchor in loop and then `.each` anchor will solve your problem, try the code above...

Comment: Thank you :) .. But url1 is always change and there is no class namely url1 . And it is dynamic . Please see the accepted answer

Comment: @Manik this will also works for dynamic urls, i'm here getting the href of anchor from class...

Comment: you can take common class for all the first urls and another common for second url whom u want to change, as i have taken url1 and url2 class, check my answer's html...